# Unity 3d call post api with json request

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I  want to call a login api in unity 3d with two json parameter username and password.

I followed many post available on stackoverflow. But my request parameters are not going on server. If I call this api from a my android app and postman and chorome, it is working fine there.

```
public IEnumerator CallLogin(string username,string password)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("username", username);
        form.AddField("password", password);

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("/apis/login", form);
        yield return www.Send();

        if (www.error != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Erro: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("All OK");
            Debug.Log("Text: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
```

So my question is how to call a post api with json request in unity 3d.

Please help.

Comment: We do it all the time.  You might flesh out how you're creating the request, the code should not be very long, and how you're receiving it on the server side.

Comment: Please post your code. Also post the json or request that you got to work with postman. This will help determine where things went bad.

Comment: @RetiredNinja : Please check my code, I am using this method to call API. You can username "yogi" and password "himanshu".

Answer (score 24):

You need to manually set the content header and the body of the message, and convert your form data string to a json string and send how parameter to `CallLogin`:

```
public IEnumerator CallLogin(string url, string logindataJsonString)
{
    var request = new UnityWebRequest (url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(logindataJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Erro: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("All OK");
        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be marked as answer. Works wonderfully :) Thanks a lot bud