# POST json string to webAPI from unity C#; HttpClient or UnityWebRequest?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to POST a json string to a web API and currently got this code:

```
async Task<Uri> Post(CapturedImage image)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(image);
    var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Debug.Log("Request Message Information:- \n\n" + response.RequestMessage + "\n");

    Debug.Log(json.ToString());

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

The code is not done yet so I'm not sure this is the type I want to return in the end (in the end I will have a new json string with information about a specific car supposedly).

Unity hangs when it comes to the line `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);` and I have to forcefully close the unity app.

**How can I use the `httpClient` successfully?** I am not using the `unityWebRequest` for the moment because I don't understand in which way `WWWForm` is being sent (like an object I guess). And I don't want a byte[] to be sent either, but a json string and I can assume that the `WWWForm` is like a json string but separated-ish. Also I don't get which type to be received in the web API either when its a `WWWForm`. Like if its a json string I just have the parameter like `(string json)`.

Am I thinking completely wrong with not using `unityWebRequest` instead of `httpClient`? I have to use json if possible.

Comment: using unitywebrequest is probably the preferred option, to send the json, the code is not dissimilar, you can post the json in the body just like you do above.

Comment: [`UnityWebRequest.Post(string URL, string data)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) also takes a simple `string` as input data not only a `WWWForm`. `I don't want a byte[] to be sent either` - well in the end everything you send will be encoded to `byte[]` ...

Comment: But use a `StartCoroutine()` and so instead of await async? What can I exchange `UnityWebRequest` with in the code? Can you show some code example? @BugFinder

Comment: @derHugo Ok! I will give it a try!

Comment: you cuold use [this](https://gist.github.com/krzys-h/9062552e33dd7bd7fe4a6c12db109a1a) (never used it but looks promising)

Comment: @derHugo it looks complicated? ^.^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`UnityWebRequest.Post(string URL, string data)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) also takes `string` as data input not only a `WWWForm`.

Usually you would use it in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

In order to get a result back you could add a simple callback

```
IEnumerator Upload(string URL, string jsonData, Action<string> callback)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URL, jsonData))
    {
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            callback?.Invoke(www.GetResponseHeader("Location"));
        }
    }
}
```

and use it with

```
StartCoroutine(Upload(someURL, someJsonData, 
    // e.g. as lambda expression
    result => 
    {
        Debug.Log(result);
    }
));
```

or with a method

```
StartCoroutine(Upload(someURL, someJsonData, HandleUploadResult);

...

private void HandleUploadResult(string result)
{
    Debug.Log(result);
}
```

---

But if you really need it to be used with `await` as said [this](https://gist.github.com/krzys-h/9062552e33dd7bd7fe4a6c12db109a1a) looks promising (though neevr tried it):

```
public class UnityWebRequestAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation asyncOp;
    private Action continuation;

    public UnityWebRequestAwaiter(UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation asyncOp)
    {
        this.asyncOp = asyncOp;
        asyncOp.completed += OnRequestCompleted;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted { get { return asyncOp.isDone; } }

    public void GetResult() { }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        this.continuation = continuation;
    }

    private void OnRequestCompleted(AsyncOperation obj)
    {
        continuation();
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static UnityWebRequestAwaiter GetAwaiter(this UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation asyncOp)
    {
        return new UnityWebRequestAwaiter(asyncOp);
    }
}
```

It looks complicated but ... you don't have to do anything with it just put it somewhere in your `Assets`.

Then as far as I understand it you can simply use something like

```
www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URL, jsonData);
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
await www.SendWebRequest();
if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    var result = www.GetResponseHeader("Location");
}
```

*There are [other sources](https://github.com/zsaladin/Asyncoroutine) which do something similar .. maybe better?*

Comment: What I specifically have to use is json really, so have tried your first example with coroutine only. I do get somewhat of a response. Its an error though `404 not found`. My url works in postman so I don't really get why the page is not found. I just have to goole it I guess ^^ Thanks for all your help once again Hugo!

Comment: also checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470315/unity-3d-call-post-api-with-json-request) it used it without `Post` and configured the rest manually ... especially try to `SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`