# Unity: sending a post request where it's data contains list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to send a post request with a list in its JSON eg:
`{ "data": [1,2,3] }`

How can I do that with webRequest and WWWForm or IMultipartFormSection.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [POST json string to webAPI from unity C#; HttpClient or UnityWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489885/post-json-string-to-webapi-from-unity-c-httpclient-or-unitywebrequest)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can review [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/posting-json-through-unitywebrequest.476254/)

Just create a class with the names of the variables you want to send and then call this class and send it with the UnityWebRequest
If you don't know how to create a class and put variables in it here is a simple example

```
public class Thename()
{
   public string _1;
   public string _2;
   public string _3;
}
public Thename _Thename;

IEnumerator RequestPOST()
{
   _Thename._1 = "Any";
   _Thename._2= "asdsad";
   _Thename._3= "Bla Bla";
   
  UnityWebRequest www = 
  UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:3000/api/rawCoords", 
  Thename);
  www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  yield return www.Send();

}
```