# Why can't I send post request to Azure Face Vision with UnityWebRequest but works with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a new unity application which uses the [API Azure Face:](https://francecentral.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)

And I have a problem with the post request of **UniteWebRequest**. I have two functions, the first uses **HttpClient** and it works!

```
public async void giveTempFaceID(string Url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string azurKey = GameManager.instance.AzurKey;
        string faceListName = GameManager.instance.faceListName;
        string UriBase = GameManager.instance.UriBaseDetect;
        string requestParameters =
            "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose," +
            "smile,facialHair,glasses,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure," +
            "noise&recognitionModel=recognition_02&returnRecognitionModel=false";
        string jsonParameters = "{\"url\": \"" + Url + "\"}";
        
        string uri = UriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", azurKey);
        
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonParameters);
        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }
        string tmpContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.Log(uri);
        Debug.Log(tmpContent);
        Debug.Log(jsonParameters);
        JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(tmpContent);

        string faceId = data[0]["faceId"].Value;
        Debug.Log(faceId);
    }

 void Start()
    {
        giveTempFaceID("http://psycho2rue.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/visage9-e1345982192269.jpg"));
    }
```

But I want to use UnityWebRequest but it doesn't work:

```
IEnumerator giveTempFaceId(string url)
    {
        string azurKey = GameManager.instance.AzurKey;
        string faceListName = GameManager.instance.faceListName;
        string UriBase = GameManager.instance.UriBaseDetect;
        string requestParameters =
            "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose," +
            "smile,facialHair,glasses,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure," +
            "noise&recognitionModel=recognition_02&returnRecognitionModel=false";
        string jsonParameters = "{\"url\": \"" + url + "\"}";
        Debug.Log(jsonParameters);
        string uri = UriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, jsonParameters))
        {
            request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
            request.SetRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", azurKey);
            request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            if (request.isNetworkError)
                Debug.Log("Network = : " + request.downloadHandler.text);
            if (request.isHttpError)
                Debug.Log("Http = : " + request.downloadHandler.text); 
        }
    }

 void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(giveTempFaceId("http://psycho2rue.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/visage9-e1345982192269.jpg"));
    }
```

With **UnityWebRequest**, I have the following error:

> {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"JSON parsing error."}}

And I don't understand why because I use the same JSON for the two samples.
I think the problems probably come from the `request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`
But I don't understand what is wrong with my code...

Edit:
The problem is UnityWebRequest encode the Data (Thanks derHugo !)

> Data Will be URLEncoded prior to transmission

Now my questions is "Can we simply say to the Post method to don't encode?"
Or I need to create a custom request like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476691/7111561)?

Comment: The problem might be that `postData Form body data. Will be URLEncoded prior to transmission.` ([source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)) so maybe you'll have to not use `UnityWebRequest.Post` but instead manually configure a "normal" `UnityWebRequest` instead. e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476691/7111561)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i understand the problem, but do you thinks it's possible to keep the Post methode and say to unity to don't encode this ?

Comment: yes ... see the last link from my comment. `UnityWebRequest.Post` is basically exactly the same as the approach there. The only difference is that it already attahces another kind of Upload- and DownloadHandlers which automatically handle that enconding.

Comment: Ho, ok i understand now, thank a lot !

Comment: Hi @derHugo Please add your comment as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 3d call post api with json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470315/unity-3d-call-post-api-with-json-request)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that

> **postData**
>   Form body data. Will be URLEncoded prior to transmission. ([from `UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

so you'll have to not use `UnityWebRequest.Post` but instead manually configure a "normal" `UnityWebRequest` instead. e.g. like this

```
IEnumerator giveTempFaceId(string url)
{
    string azurKey = GameManager.instance.AzurKey;
    string faceListName = GameManager.instance.faceListName;
    string UriBase = GameManager.instance.UriBaseDetect;
    string requestParameters =
        "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,headPose," +
        "smile,facialHair,glasses,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure," +
        "noise&recognitionModel=recognition_02&returnRecognitionModel=false";
    string jsonParameters = "{\"url\": \"" + url + "\"}";
    Debug.Log(jsonParameters);
    string uri = UriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest(uri, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST))
    {
        byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonParameters);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", azurKey);
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError)
            Debug.Log("Network = : " + request.downloadHandler.text);
        if (request.isHttpError)
            Debug.Log("Http = : " + request.downloadHandler.text); 
    }
}
```