# How to combine url and string for api call

Tags: api, http, unity-game-engine, url

I'm trying to combine a url and string at runtime and then call it.

```
public static Uri Append(this Uri uri, params string[] paths)
    {
        return new Uri(paths.Aggregate(uri.AbsoluteUri, (current, path) => string.Format("{0}/{1}", current.TrimEnd('/'), path.TrimStart('/'))));
    }

var url = new Uri("https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=").Append(_PlayerName).AbsoluteUri;
```

However when I call it, this error is returned:

```
Failed the request: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

The url looks like this

```
https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=/%22KidKiwi91%22
```

I know the error is caused by the concatenation of the url and string because it I make it all one url and not combine them in runtime it works.

Other things i've tried:

```
string url = "urlgoeshere=" + playername;
string url = UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL("urlgoeshere" + playername);

string url_q = "urlgoeshere=" + playername;
var url=new Uri(url_q);
```

It's called using this

```
private IEnumerator GetJSON(string url, System.Action<string> callback)
    {
        failed = false;

        //Debug.Log(url);
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            webRequest.certificateHandler = new BypassCertificate();

            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string error = webRequest.error;

            if (error != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed the request: " + error);
                failed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                callback?.Invoke(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                //Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path.Combine for URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls)

Comment: No, i've tried half of them and same error on all of them

Comment: Have you tried debugging the exact final URL and compare it to one that works that you hardcode? In other words: Are you sure the issue is with the code or is your URL incorrect at all? A `400` means that the server was reached correctly but doesn't understand the request ... can you post a URL that is working correctly when you hardcode it and tell us what exactly all your variables hold? I'm pretty sure there is an `/` too much and it should rather be `https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=%22KidKiwi91%22`

Comment: @derHugo 
Working url: https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=KidKiwi91
Concated url: https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName="KidKiwi91"

Looks like it's adding the quotes

Comment: That would probably be the `%22` .. how exactly does your `_PlayerName` look like? you could probably avoid it by using `_PlayerName.Trim('"')` (it is `'  "  '` a bit hard to see ;) )

Comment: _PlayerName is just a standard string KidKiwi91, it seems by doing this on the concatenated string             url2 = url2.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim(); it works.

Comment: check my reply to this and if help delete this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470315/unity-3d-call-post-api-with-json-request/45476691#45476691

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string url_q = "https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=" + 
playername;

var url=new Uri(url_q);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error

Comment: pls provide the remaining code, where did you want to put this url?

Comment: Added to the original post

Comment: what  value you got in url variable?